# The Crown of the Torah

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This should be an easy one if you have a Bible handy:

> My name is Kether Torah,
>   the Crown of the Torah.
>
> I am a pillar of righteousness,
>   and a foundation of mercy.
>
> I am four, and three, and two, and one;
>   and beside me there is none other.
>
> Those who hear me have life;
>   they that disobey me shall surely die.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you the:

> 10 Commandments

Explanation:

My name is Kether Torah,
the Crown of the Torah.

> This refers to the fact that we are looking into something from Judaism (probably the first 5 books of the Bible)

I am a pillar of righteousness,

> We are looking for something pertaining to morality - could be quite symbolic.

and a foundation stone of mercy.

> Foundation makes me think of "stone"... i.e. a tablet perhaps.

I am four, and three, and two, and one;

> SURELY some numerical trick. Possibly pointing to a passage. But I notice the sum is 10, and product is 24.

and beside me there is none other.

> This is said by God in the 10 commandments (the first).

Those who hear me have life;
those who disobey me shall surely die.

> God says this kind of thing frequently according to the Bible. Always with regards to a threat for disobedience to a command/law.

The evidence for guessing the Ark of the Covenant or the Ten Commandments is strong enough.

---

`Regarding the Kether Torah:`
Courtesy of OP:

> [image: Ten Commandments]
>
> [Picture of the **Ten Commandments** with the words כתר תורה (*Kether Torah*) written prominently above.]
>
> The identification of the Ten Commandments with the **Crown of the Torah** comes from the ancient Jewish practice of [gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria), whereby the numerical value of the words *Kether Torah* is equal to that of *Aseret Ha-Devarim* ("the Ten Commandments").

Comment: Very good, I see everything accounted for. (Btw, no specific chapter/verse number was intended, just the number 10 and the gist of the 1st commandment.) Well done!

Answer (score 1):

> Headstone?
>  Some jewish people believe a good name is what is superior, "one crown of the torah" which a headstone has inscribed
> a pillar of righteousness as we honor those who fall before us and mercy on their deaths.
>  an equestrian headstone has meanings depending on how many legs (4) it has touching the ground.
> there is none other that is the same as each is different inscriptions and no one is beside as they are deceased
> those who keep them have life as there not planted yet or not sold
>  if you violate your "head" you shall surely die.

Answer (score 0):

> [image: Ten Commandments]
>
> [Picture of the **Ten Commandments** with the words כתר תורה (*Kether Torah*) written prominently above.]
>
> The identification of the Ten Commandments with the **Crown of the Torah** comes from the ancient Jewish practice of [gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria), whereby the numerical value of the words *Kether Torah* is equal to that of *Aseret Ha-Devarim* ("the Ten Commandments").

Comment: nice additional information